# Extjs Bar Chart For Live Data

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, bar-chart, extjs4.2

My Application get live data from server, which includes number of operations executed and time at which it executed.

Now I am trying to implement a bar chart out of it which looks like splunk event chart which displays bars for every minute and should allow user to zoom in and zoom out.

I tried extjs stackedBarchart but it didnt looked like the one which i want to use.

Any ideas?

Appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: Well, you say it didn't look like you wanted, but you're not clear at all what you're looking for.

Comment: What other options have you tried so far?  Have you looked into [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) or the other charts available in [extjs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/charts/BarRenderer.html)?